# Equivalence of the definitions of a sheaf in SGA4 and in "Categories and Sheaves"

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topology, sites

I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2463353/660) on Mathematics Stack Exchange, but got no answer.

I don't understand why the definition of a sheaf (Definition 17.3.1 (ii)) given in the book

[KS] **[Categories and Sheaves](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-27950-4)** by Kashiwara and Schapira

is equivalent to the definition of a sheaf (Definition 2.1) given in

[V] Verdier, Exposé II, SGA4, [http://www.normalesup.org/~forgogozo/SGA4/02/02.pdf](http://www.normalesup.org/%7Eforgogozo/SGA4/02/02.pdf)

To simplify, let me consider only set-valued presheaves.

Here is, in the terminology of [KS], how I understand the two definitions. (Warning: my understanding might be incorrect!)

Let $\mathcal U$ be a universe, let $X$ be a small site and let $F$ be a $\mathcal U$-set-valued presheaf over $X$. Then:

- $F$ is a sheaf in the sense of [V] if $F(f)$ is an isomorphism for any $A$ in $(\mathcal C_X)^\wedge$, any $U$ in $\mathcal C_X$, and any local isomorphism $f:A\to U$ **which is a monomorphism**,
- $F$ is a sheaf in the sense of [KS] if $F(f)$ is an isomorphism for any $A$ in $(\mathcal C_X)^\wedge$, any $U$ in $\mathcal C_X$, and any local isomorphism $f:A\to U$.

The difference is that the local isomorphism $f$ is supposed to be a *monomorphism* in Verdier's definition.

A "KS-sheaf" is of course a "V-sheaf", but I'm unable to prove the converse.

Comment: I think these might be equivalent by the argument that proves "Ken Brown's lemma" in model category theory.

Comment: @DylanWilson - Thanks! Unfortunately I know nothing about model categories. You're most welcome to give further details in a new comment or in an answer. (I may accept an answer I don't fully understand.)

Comment: I've just noticed that the equivalence of the definitions follows from Proposition 5.3, implication "(i) $\implies$ (ii bis)", in Verdier’s Exposé http://www.normalesup.org/~forgogozo/SGA4/02/02.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\im{im}$Actually I couldn't quite figure out how to do a Ken Brown sort of argument, but here's an argument that works:

Let $L$ denote the *usual* sheafification functor, a la Grothendieck and Verdier etc. Then I claim it's enough to show $L$ sends local epimorphisms to epimorphisms and local monomorphisms to monomorphisms. Indeed, if this is the case then $L$ takes local isomorphisms to epi-monomorphisms, and such things are isomorphisms in toposes.

Since $L$ preserves finite limits, we need only check that $L$ takes local epis to epis (since $A \to B$ is a local mono iff $A \to A\times_BA$ is a local epi). But that's not so bad: If $A \to B$ is a local epimorphism then the map $\im(A \to B) \to B$ is a local epimorphism and a monomorphism, and hence a monic, local isomorphism. But $L$ preserves images (since they're computed as colimits and L preserves those) and takes monic, local isomorphisms to isomorphisms. Thus $LA \to LB$ has the property that $\im(LA \to LB) \to LB$ is an isomorphism (NB: that image is computed *in the category of sheaves*), and so the map is epi in the category of sheaves, which is what we wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this awesome answer! Would you have enough time to answer also the MSE question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2463353/660 - for instance by a link to the above answer of yours? (I would of course upvote it and accept it.)

Comment: I suddenly realize that I didn't understand your argument. In the penultimate sentence you write that $L$ "takes monic, local isomorphisms to isomorphisms". Why is this true?

Comment: Isn't that the defining feature of $L$? A 'monic, local isomorphism' with target a representable is the same as a covering sieve I think. But every monic, local isomorphism is built out of these from colimits (express the target as a colimit of representables, and pull-back the source to each of these, getting covering sieves throughout by the axioms of a topology)

Comment: Thanks! One of the things you're saying is that, given an object $U$ of $\mathcal C$ and $S\hookrightarrow U$ a covering sieve viewed as a subobject of $U$ in $\mathcal C^\wedge$, the morphism $LS\to LU$ is an isomorphism. Right? If so, could you explain this as simply as possible?

Comment: It's basically the definition of $L$ that it inverts those, but if you have a different definition in mind that's fine: The map $LS \to LU$ is an isomorphism iff for all sheaves $F$, $\mathrm{Hom}(LU, F) \to \mathrm{Hom}(LS, F)$ is an isomorphism. Now use that $L$ is left adjoint to the inclusion and the definition of $F$ being a sheaf.

Comment: Very clear explanation! I hope that I have now understood your argument for good...

Answer (score 3):

I have found a very elementary proof, where the presheaves are allowed to take values in any category $\mathcal{A}$ with enough limits (however Dylan’s [argument](https://mathoverflow.net/a/283271) can be used to show this in the same generality by using Prop. 17.3.2 of [KS](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-27950-4)). Let $F$ be a presheaf satisfying the Verdier definition. We shall first show that $F$ is separated in the sense of KS. For this let $f:A\rightarrow U$ be a local isomorphism. Factor $f=i\circ g$ with $g:A\rightarrow \operatorname{im}(f)$. Then $i$ is a monic local isomorphism and $g$ is epic. Consequently $F(i)$ is an isomorphism and as $F$ commutes with limits, $F(g)$ is a mono morphism. In particular $F(f)$ is Mono. This shows that $F$ is KS separated.

Now we shall show that $F(f)$ must even be an iso.
For this, notice that as $f$ is a local monomorphism we also have that $g$ is a local monomorphism. Now as $g$ is a strict epimorphism (as we are in a category of sets), we get that
$$A\times_{\operatorname{im}(f)}A\rightrightarrows A \rightarrow \operatorname{im}(f)$$ is a right exact sequence (i.e. $\operatorname{im}(f)$ is a cokernel of the two projections $p_1$ and $p_2$).
As $F$ commutes with limits, we get the left exact sequence
$$F(\operatorname{im}(f))\rightarrow F(A) \rightrightarrows F(A\times_{\operatorname{im}(f)}A).$$

Now as $g$ is a local monomorphism, we have that the diagonal map $\Delta:A\rightarrow A\times_{\operatorname{im}(f)}A $ is a local epimorphism. Hence, as $F$ is KS separated, proposition 17.3.3 implies that $F(\Delta)$ is monic. As
$F(\Delta)\circ F(p_1)= F(\Delta)\circ F(p_2) $, we get $F(p_1)=F(p_2)$ and hence the last exact sequence forces $F(\operatorname{im}(f))\rightarrow F(A) $ to be an iso. But this morphism is $F(g)$. As $F(i)$ is an iso, so is $F(f)$ then.

Comment: You are being careless about your hypotheses. Clearly you are assuming that $\mathcal{A}$ has some kind of epi–mono factorisation. You seem also make the common mistake of equating the sheaf condition to preservation of limits.

Comment: Where do I need this assumption on $\mathcal{A}$? The factorisation of $f$ is done in the category $Psh(C,\operatorname{Set})$, not $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: You wrote: "where the presheaves are allowed to take values in any category $\mathcal{A}$ with enough limits". If you don't work in that generality then there is no need to write it.

Comment: Here $F$ is considered to be extended to a contra variant functor $Psh(C,\operatorname{Set}) \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ as described  on Page 408 of KS, line 6. $F$ then commutes with small limits.

Comment: In the original question it was written “ To simplify, let me consider only set-valued presheaves.” As my argument does not need this simplification, I figured, it would be appropriate to say “ where the presheaves are allowed to take values in any category 
$\mathcal{A}$ with enough limits”

Comment: That is a very unusual way of doing things... but yes, then it is true. You should clarify your notation.

Comment: I don’t have a feeling on what is considered usual notation. I assumed, that the conventions of KS were standard. What would you recommend me to clarify?

Comment: I believe KS is considered unorthodox. I don't often see it recommended as an introduction or as a reference.